# How to add '- {}' value with helm --set parameter?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am stuck with the following issue. I am trying to implement kubernetes networkpolices via values provided to helm.

**values.yml**

```
...
networkpolicy: []
  # Allows all ingress and egress
  # - name: my-app
  #   podSelector:
  #     matchLabels:
  #       app: my-app
  #   egress:
  #   - {}
  #   ingress:
  #   - {}
...
```

Running install command:

```
helm --debug --v 3 --kubeconfig $kubeconf upgrade --install $name \
        $helmchart \
        --set networkpolicy[0].name="my-app" \
        --set networkpolicy[0].podSelectory.matchLabels.app="my-app" \
        --set networkpolicy[0].egress[0]="''{}''" \
```

Error message:

```
...
helm.go:84: [debug] error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(NetworkPolicy.spec.egress[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.networking.v1.NetworkPolicyEgressRule: got "string", expected "map"
...
```

How can I set the "- {}" with `--set networkpolicy[0].egress[0] ...` ???

Thanks.

Comment: The `helm install --set` syntax is...unique and complicated.  Can you put this in standard YAML syntax in a separate file, and then use `helm install -f` to supply that file as additional values?

Comment: The reason for using the `--set` is to prevent a separate values YAML.

Comment: Understood, but can you please provide the yaml file mentioned by David? This information can be useful for us with helping you.